# Compare image edges with margin in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matching, contour, edge-detection

I have two almost similar images with the difference that the shapes in the second image are a little different. Most of the time smaller, but can be larger. Also the shape count in one image can range from ~10 to >100 and can get relatively close to each other.
It would look something like this (Notice: both images would be not transparent):

[image: Image 1]

The black triangle is image 1, the grey triangle is image 2.

Now i want to add a predefined margin (3px here - to both sides of the contour) to the edges of image 1 and test if the edges of the second image are in "the same" range as the first image. If not, display that visually:

[image]

Top left: Small difference between the two images (visualized by red outline)

Bottom right: "Same" edge -> No difference

How can i best accomplish this?

I'm using OpenCV with C++

Comment: decide to drow a red contour or not applying the area of each contour, by crossing comparisons. First find outer and inner contour of each, then calculate the areas, then compare and decide, you need FindContours(), and contourArea()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the shapes are at the same positions in both images and you just need the markers on an image without additional information, this simple trick could do it.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat img1 = imread("D:/1.png");
    Mat img2 = imread("D:/2.png");
    Mat diff;
    absdiff(img1, img2, diff);
    cv::threshold(diff, diff, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat markers;
    int minRadiusDiff = 2;
    erode(diff, markers, Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), minRadiusDiff / 2);
    imwrite("D:/out.png", markers);
}
```

Here are some example images:

[image]

The triangle becomes much bigger, the wobbly thing becomes much smaller and the quad ony shrinks slightly.

[image]

So we would like to have the triangle and the wobble marked, but not the quad.

[image]

And that is exactly our result.

Comment: i'm gonna test it tomorrow, but it looks promisings, thanks :)

Comment: If it does not, feel free to post some of your actual images, and I will see what I can do.

Comment: And is it possible to use float rather than int (to make it even more exact)?

Comment: Since this is the number of iterations for the erosion, no. With this approach you would have to scale up the image. For example when you want 3.4, you would have to scale up by 5 and then use 17.